# Conda Environment is not listed after creation and environment inconsistency

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables, conda

I wanted to create an environment using conda prompt but I am getting this error a lot of times.

Initially the command I wrote:
`conda create -n my_env python=3.7`, no error arrives but neither the environment is created

```
(base) C:\Users\cosmo>conda create -n my_env python=3.7
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.7.12
  latest version: 4.10.3

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



(base) C:\Users\cosmo>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3
IP                       C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3\envs\IP
IncomePred               C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3\envs\IncomePred


(base) C:\Users\cosmo>
```

Later I just tried this `conda create --name my_env python=3.7`
The output,

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.7.12
  latest version: 4.10.3

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

If I try to update

```
(base) C:\Users\cosmo>conda update -n base -c defaults conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: -
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:
\
  - defaults/win-64::alabaster==0.7.12=py37_0
  - defaults/win-64::anaconda==2019.10=py37_0
  - defaults/win-64::anaconda-client==1.7.2=py37_0
  - defaults/win-64::anaconda-navigator==1.9.7=py37_0
  - defaults/noarch::anaconda-project==0.8.3=py_0
  - defaults/win-64::asn1crypto==1.0.1=py37_0
  - defaults/win-64::astroid==2.3.1=py37_0
.....
```

And like this huge number of package names appears and then the issue goes into loop

Finally, When I tried this
`conda create --name my_env`
The environment was created and when i activated it and tried to run anything, the same error came
up everytime
`Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.`
If I try to install something that doesn't work either

```
(Incomepred) C:\Users\cosmo>conda install jupyter notebook
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.7.12
  latest version: 4.10.3

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



(Incomepred) C:\Users\cosmo>jupyter notebook
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Conda Info

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\cosmo\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\cosmo\.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.12
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.1
       base environment : C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\cosmo\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\cosmo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\cosmo\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\cosmo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

And the user agent details

Comment: the first error was because you wrote ```python-3.7``` instead of ```python=3.7```. What do you mean with 'when I activate and try to run something'? What do you type in the console and what is the exact output?

Comment: @flyinthelotion Please have a look I have added the details in the question description. doing python=3.7 doesn't give any error but neither is the env created.

Comment: can you update conda first by running ```conda update -n base -c defaults conda```, then try to create your new env, and activate it using ```conda activate my_env```?

Comment: I did and the output description is in ques, the number of packages appear and then again the whole thing goes in loop @flyinthelotion
At another question similar issue, they suggested down versioning but that doesn't run either, but I hope the version is not the issue. I might need to reinstall everything i guess

Comment: Please focus the question, i.e., remove the superfluous section on `python-3.7` and change the title to what the actual problem is, which seems more like, "*Environment not listed after creation*"

Comment: It is listed actually but the conda command is creating issues. Especially after activating the env, I can't install anything. `The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully` is one of the errors and the other is the one above where I try to install jupyter in an env. @merv

Comment: Focus on updating Conda. Your statement that "*the issue goes into loop*" sounds like you need to wait it out to finish. It may be helpful to try: `conda update -n base --override-channels -c defaults conda` But you really need to let that command finish or consider scrapping the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Anaconda and removed all related packages, installed everything again. It solved the issue completely.